# redirect a loop within a loop for only "else"

Tags: java

I'm a total beginner and am working on a practice assignment. I need to be able to re-print the same addition problem if the user has answered incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to do that. All my attempts have lead to a new random addition problem appearing or adding another new random to the original, which is also not desired. I'm sure it's simple, but I am lost. Thanks in advance for any tips!

```
package ov3uppgift8;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ov3uppgift8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       Random rand = new Random ();

        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");
        int ans;
        do {    
            int a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int b = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
            System.out.print(a + " + " + b +" = ");
            ans = input.nextInt();    

            if (ans==(a+b)) {
                System.out.println("CORRECT!");
            } else if (ans==0) {
                System.out.println("Good bye!");
            } else if (ans!=(a+b)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect, try again.");
            }
      } while (ans!=0);     
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't create a and b inside the loop if the answer is not correct. You create them randomly with new values every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see modification inline:

```
    package ov3uppgift8;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Ov3uppgift8 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           Random rand = new Random ();

            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");
                int ans;
                do
                {    
                int a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                int b = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    System.out.print(a + " + " + b +" = ");
                ans = input.nextInt();    

                if (ans==(a+b))

                {
                    System.out.println("CORRECT!");
                }
                 else if (ans==0) 

                {
                    System.out.println("Good bye!");

                }

                else if (ans!=(a+b))

                {
                    // here you keep asking the user over and over 
                    //until they give the right result
                    do{
                        System.out.println("Incorrect, try again.");
                        //show again the equation to the user
                        System.out.print(a + " + " + b +" = ");
                        ans = input.nextInt();
                    }while(ans!=(a+b));
                }
                }
          while (ans!=0);     
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted something similar on my own and just wasn't getting it correct. Is there a way to add in the new loop "do" to have it re-print the addition problem, without creating a new one?

Comment: I added the re-print of the addition problem in the code

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify your code a little bit, don't overthink. You generate answers every time you get into the loop, generate your numbers outside so they stay consistent, also, a do-while, isn't necessary, just break your loop if the answer is correct or they placed 0. Also, you need to make sure that the user entered a number, so a try-catch should be placed while getting the input.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random ();

System.out.println("*****************");
System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
System.out.println("*****************");
System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");

int a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
int b = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

int ans;

while (true) {
    System.out.printf("%d + %d = ?%n", a, b);

    try {
        ans = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
        continue;
    }

    if (ans == 0) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        break;
    } else if (ans == a + b) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to try it out and try to make sense of it. I really am brand new to this, so have not used try/ catch before. So much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple source code and similar to you (minor change):

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.println("*****************");
    System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
    System.out.println("*****************");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");

    int ans, a, b;
    ans = a = b = 0;

    do {    
        a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        b = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.print(a + " + " + b + " = ");

        try{
            //Getting input as String and casting to Integer
            ans = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            if (ans == 0) {
                System.out.println("Good bye!");
            } else if (ans == (a + b)) {
                System.out.println("CORRECT!");
            } else if (ans != (a + b)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect, try again.");
            }

        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println(nfe);
        }

    } while (ans != 0);

}
```

Comment: This is again using try/ catch which I've never tried before. This will help me to understand a new concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class generateNum{
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int a=rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    int b=rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    public void generate(){

         System.out.print(a + " + " + b +" = ");
     }
    public int getsum(){
        return a+b;
    }
}
public class Test02 {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");

                int ans;      

                generateNum gnum = new generateNum();
                gnum.generate();
                ans = input.nextInt();
                int com=gnum.getsum();

                do
                {    
                if (ans==com)

                {
                    System.out.println("CORRECT!");
                    gnum = new generateNum();
                    gnum.generate();
                    ans = input.nextInt();
                    com=gnum.getsum();
                }
                 else if (ans==0) 

                {
                    System.out.println("Good bye!");
                }

                else if (ans!=com)

                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect, try again.");
                    gnum.generate();
                    ans = input.nextInt();
                }
                }
          while (ans!=0);     
        }
}
```

Comment: So far I've only used Random and have not tried generateNum. This is something new in my toolbelt! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes in your condition. Update your else-if(ans!=(a+b)) block.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       Random rand = new Random ();

        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println("* MATH TRAINING *");
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 to close program.");
            int ans;
            do
            {    
            int a = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
            int b = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                System.out.print(a + " + " + b +" = ");
            ans = input.nextInt();    

            if (ans==(a+b))

            {
                System.out.println("CORRECT!");
            }
             else if (ans==0) 

            {
                System.out.println("Good bye!");

            }

              else if (ans!=(a+b))

                {

                 boolean flag = false;
                 do{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect, try again.(0 for skip)");
                        int againAns = input.nextInt();
                        if(againAns == (a+b)){
                            System.out.println("CORRECT!");
                        flag = true;
                        }else if(againAns == 0){
                        System.out.println("You skip the answer..");
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    }while(flag != true);
                }
                }while (ans!=0);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not supposed to allow the user to skip the question, but that is likely going to come up soon in my course. I'm sure this will be useful soon, and good for me to see another example of boolean as I'm still wrapping head around them. Thanks!

Comment: if you don't want to allow the user to skip the question in that case just remove else if(againAns == 0) portion from the code and don't be hesitate to upvote the relevant answer. Best of luck for further :).